# Date.parse() not working properly in Mozilla Firefox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have the string dateTime value **"01-01-2013 12:00:00 AM"** and parsed to DateTime using `Date.parse("01-01-2013 12:00:00 AM")`. This is working fine in Google Chrome and IE browser. But not working in **Firefox**. Anyone help how to parse this specific string to dateTime value in **Mozilla Firefox**.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please remember to accept it. If not, please let me know!

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** You're using an invalid date format for this context, which Chrome and IE just happen to handle.

**Full answer:**

The specification only requires a JavaScript implementation to recognize certain formats in `Date.parse`. Specifically,

> It accepts the RFC2822 / IETF date syntax (RFC2822 Section 3.3), e.g.
>   "`Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT`". It understands the continental US
>   time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset,
>   for example, "`Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 +0430`" (4 hours, 30 minutes
>   east of the Greenwich meridian). If a time zone is not specified and
>   the string is in an ISO format recognized by ES5, UTC is assumed. GMT
>   and UTC are considered equivalent. The local time zone is used to
>   interpret arguments in RFC2822 Section 3.3 format (or any format not
>   recognized as ISO 8601 in ES5) that do not contain time zone
>   information.
>
> **ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format support**
>
> The date time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For example,
>   "`2011-10-10`" (just date) or "`2011-10-10T14:48:00`" (date and time) can
>   be passed and parsed.

Your example, `01-01-2013 12:00:00 AM`, is not one of those formats. Some browsers may parse it anyway, depending on the JavaScript engine they are using, but it's non-standard. Chrome and IE happen to recognize it, but Firefox returns `NaN`, which is compliant with the spec:

> The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to
>   the standard format the function may fall back to any
>   implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing
>   algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or dates containing illegal element
>   values in ISO formatted strings shall cause `Date.parse()` to return
>   `NaN`.

See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for more details.